# What are the two physical terms embedded in the word "direction"?

Tags: kinematics, terminology

In my mother tongue during the physics classes I learnt that we had two specific different technical terms for the concept “direction”, they were *sentido* and *direção*.

The prior meant direction in the sense of which specific linear direction a certain body moves *towards*, and the latter meant merely the direction *along* which such body moves, i.e. the latter doesn’t specify the direction towards which the body moves, but merely the line along which it moves. Therefore the drawing representation of the prior has an arrow and in the latter there is no arrow, just a line. We can say broadly that the latter included the prior, plus the counter-direction.

What are the correct and clear physical terms in English to define those two different physical concepts?

Comment: In mathematics, you might call these vectors and rays. A ray is an element of a projective vector space, i.e. it means 'a vector up to multiplying it by any number, including $-1$'.

Comment: Another two closely related words would be "heading" (for "sentido") and "path" (for "direcao").

Comment: @Steve I think a path might be curvy, whilst "direção" is always straight

Comment: A duplicate of at least two questions. Unfortunately I am not able to find them.

Comment: It could be Verse for the arrowed path and Direction for the path itself.  But I am not too sure to make it answer.

Comment: @Aónio, I think the word "line" is possibly the best word in general, since that strongly implies straightness (unless it is qualified with another word, such as in "curved line"). The word "ray" as suggested by Knzhou is a good alternative in some contexts, but that strongly refers to a thing which by its nature follows a straight line (like a "light ray") or the path which *has been* taken (a "ray-trace"), not a reference to the line itself (nor the path that *will be* taken). No other word comes to mind that has any stronger connotation of straightness or directness than the word "line".

Comment: @Aónio - It would be helpful if you could give an example sentence (in Portuguese)  where you typically use  *direção* and an example where you use *sentido* as opposed to *direção* and you cannot use the latter. As both words come from  Latin, I would suspect that the equivalent words in English, which also stem from Latin (directly or via French) will have the same meaning.

Comment: @Steve in Portuguese we would say that a ruler has a certain "direção" (for example it's very common to use expressions such as "horizontal direction") and a car has a certain "sentido", and according to my physics teacher, they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

I think that, in the context of movements, the Portuguese words *direção* and *sentido*  have the same meaning as the words *direction* and *sense* in English. Direction and *direção* both refer to the goal (or target) of a movement. Sense and *sentido* both mean one of two possible opposite directions of motion, like in a one way, or in the left or right hand rotation.

Comment: It's interesting that in English, we have a "sense of direction", but the word "sense" alone doesn't seem to have the same connotations as in Portuguese.

Comment: @Steve - You are right. In the English "sense of direction", sense has a completely different meaning!

Answer (score 2):

Though it is uncommon, in English one may talk about *direction* vs *alignment*. The former is associated with vector quantities, like force, velocity, electric field, and so on. Thing that fall into the latter are the principal curvatures of a surface, the alignment of a linear-polarized radar signal (vertical is both up and down), or the alignments of deformation caused by the passage of gravitational waves. Though these examples are mathematically different, they are generically tensor quantities.

Comment: +1 That is definitely another good word JEB, "alignment".

Comment: @JEB - Good to point out the English word  "alignment". This is, however, different to the meaning of the Portuguese word *sentido* of the OP's question. The Portuguese equivalent of alignment, with the same meaning,  is *alinhamento*.